# ImportError: cannot import name 'wrapper' from 'tabula' Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabula, tabula-py

I have Java installed and the path setup, I can execute java -version and javac -version from the command line successfully.  When I try and run the following script I get an error.

```
import tabula
from tabula import wrapper
df = wrapper.read_pdf('singapore.pdf')
```

Error is

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'wrapper' from 'tabula'
```

I have tabula-py installed and have checked that tabula does not exist.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Ok I am such an idiot, I had my python script named "tabula.py" which was causing the issue.  I'm new to python and didn't realise you can't use a filename with the name as some other module you import.  Everything is working now, hooray!!